How can I identify groups based on multiple overlapping criteria?
Imagine you have two arbitary categorical variables, a and b:
d <- structure(list(a = c("e", "c", "d", "b", "c", "a", "d", "f"), b = c(5, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 6)), row.names = 1:8, class = "data.frame")
d

  a b
1 e 5
2 c 2
3 d 3
4 b 1
5 c 3
6 a 1
7 d 4
8 f 6

How would you identify groups where either a or b can indicate membership of the same group? For example, rows 2 and 5 are both in group "c", while rows 3 and 7 are both in group "d". Simultaneously, rows 3 and 5 are both in group "3". Therefore, rows 2, 3, 5, and 7 are all in the same group.
The result should look like this:
  a b group
1 e 5     1
2 c 2     2
3 d 3     2
4 b 1     3
5 c 3     2
6 a 1     3
7 d 4     2
8 f 6     4

Here is my very inelegant solution that only works for two variables:
d$group <- NA_integer_
u <- unique(d$a)
d$id <- 1:nrow(d)
e <- d

for(i in seq_along(u)) {
  g1 <- e[e$a == u[i],]$b
  g2 <- e[e$b %in% g1,]$a
  g3 <- e[e$a %in% g2,]
  N <- if (all(is.na(d$group))) 1 else max(d$group, na.rm = T) + 1
  d$group[d$id %in% g3$id] <- N
  e <- d[is.na(d$group),]
}

d

> d
  a b group id
1 e 5     1  1
2 c 2     2  2
3 d 3     2  3
4 b 1     3  4
5 c 3     2  5
6 a 1     3  6
7 d 4     2  7
8 f 6     4  8


This seems like a quite easy task, but I don't understand the criteria you are using for creating groups in your example. What do rows 2, 3, 5, and 7 share in common in order to expect them to be in the same group? Is the condition for group something like b being less than 5 and more than 1? In that case, what is the overlapping criteria? It is not clear.

The data are completely arbitrary - the letters and numbers in columns a and b don't mean anything at all, and the numbers could equally be a string. But for a more tangible example, Imagine you have a table of countries and you are trying to identify duplicates. Column A is country name, eg. "US, "United States", "US" etc. Column B is capital city, eg. NA, "Washington DC", "Washington DC". How do you identify that these are all the same country (without knowing anything more than what is in the data!)

Imagine you know nothing except that rows are in the same group if the values are equal!

Your descriptions are unclear & fragmented. So it's no wonder you can't easily find a solution. Readers have to guess what you mean. Instead, answer this: What condition tells you whether the row (r.a, r.b, r.group) is in the result r? Moreover that when clear can be mechanically translated into a query.

@philipxy, ironically, I don't understand your comment. Could you state it clearly please?

What is the 1st thing you don't understand?

I have two rows here, with values (t1.a, t1.b) & (t2.a, t2.b). Under what condition are they in the same group? (In terms of r.a & r.b plus the business situation and/or the value of the input table d.) (We could define a function f(t,a,b) evaluating that condition.) I have another row of values here (r.a, r.b, r.group). Under what condition is it in the result r? (In terms of r.a, r.b & r.group plus the business situation and/or the original value of the input table & presumably in terms of the condition/f in my previous question.) (Apparently needing the implicit d id column.)

Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?

Take a look at igraph::components:
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(d)
comps <- components(g)$membership
d$group <- comps[match(as.character(d$a), names(comps))]
d
#>   a b group
#> 1 e 5     1
#> 2 c 2     2
#> 3 d 3     2
#> 4 b 1     3
#> 5 c 3     2
#> 6 a 1     3
#> 7 d 4     2
#> 8 f 6     4

